# Delphi - Reading a file signature and compare them

Tags: delphi, hex, digital-signature

I need of a little help in delphi. I have search in very places but i can't find the answer for my question.

How i can read a file signature(4 bytes in my case) and put the value in HEX into a string? The signature my program will have to identify is $4E4553A1.

I need to test if the file, for example. C:\Happy.bin. Have this signature. To avoid people to put wrong format files in my software. Signature are the first 4 bytes in it.

Thank you so  much, english isn't my first language, so sorry for the mistakes. Love you all

Comment: If you need to compare the first four byte values then simply compare the byte values. Why do you want to convert the bytes into a hex string representation?

Comment: Yes, can be like it!! I just don't know how to do it :( I need to compare a sigture, just it.

Comment: Then you should ask about that ... please update your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the easiest. You call it and pass in the filename.

```
function CheckSignature(aFilename: string): Boolean;
var
  signature: UInt32;
  myFile: TFileStream;
begin
  myFile := TFileStream.Create(aFilename, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    if myFile.Read(signature, SizeOf(signature)) = SizeOf(signature) then
      Result := (signature = $A153454E)
    else
      Result := False;
  finally
    myFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The signature is reversed because of the way the integer stores it's data (little endian).

To use this function you would call it like this:

```
begin
  if CheckSignature('C:\Happy.bin') then
    ShowMessage('Matched')
  else
    ShowMessage('Didn''t match');
end;
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. Result is always 0. How i test with this code?

Comment: Try swapping the comparison value back to exactly what you originally showed: `Result := (signature = $4E4553A1);` Alternatively, define a 4-byte `const` array containing the exact signature bytes you are interested in, then read the file signature into a 4-byte array instead of a UInt32, and then pass the two arrays to `CompareMem()`.

Comment: What if the file is shorter than 4 bytes?

Comment: @VictorMelo I added an example.